# addGlobalScope withCount relationship's relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have a 3 models: Phone, Product and Store.

A phone has many Product which belongs to a Store.

I am trying to add a golbal scope so that every time I load a phone, products and stores counts are loaded automatically.

products_count works fine, however stores_count is a bit tricky since store is not a Phone's relationship but a Product's.

I have tried the following but it gives me an error "Method getRelated does not exist.", I assume because stores() now returns a collection.

Any ideas as to how I could add the stores_count?

```
 public static function boot(){

    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('products', function ($builder){

        $builder->withCount('products');
        $builder->withCount('stores');  <----- gives error
    });
}

public function products(){

    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}

public function stores(){
    $store_ids = $this->products()->get(['store_id'])->unique();

    return Store::find($store_ids);
}
```

**Update after @Sandeesh answer.**

I tried to use hasManyThrough but it returns an empty collection which is wrong.
When I dd($phone->products); I can see 7 products which have 3 different stores.

```
public function stores(){

    return $this->hasManyThrough(Store::class, Product::class,
        'store_id', 'id');
}
```

Database schema

```
Phone
-id

Product
-id
-phone_id
-product_id
-store_id

Store
-id
```

**Update 2**

So I managed to get the produced query from the stores() method above.

```
select `phones`.*, 
(select count(*) from `products` where `phones`.`id` = `products`.`phone_id`) as `products_count`, 
(select count(*) from `stores` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `stores`.`id` where `phones`.`id` = `products`.`store_id`) as `stores_count` 
from `phones` where `slug` = ? limit 1
```

The problem is in the third line. The query is messed up, not sure what is wrong with the relationship though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `hasManyThrough`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Store::class, Product::class);
}
```

Edit

This should give you what you need. But eager loading is always better

```
protected $appends  = [
    'productCount',
    'storeCount'
];

public function getProductCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->products()->count();
}

public function getStoreCountAttribute()
{
    return Store::whereIn('id', $this->products()->pluck('store_id')->toArray())->count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work as it is, I updated my question.

Comment: can you add the store structure? seems like you missed it

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me Sandeesh, however I am trying to avoid doing it in memory for performance reasons. I suppose there is a way of doing it through sql, isn't there?

Comment: @George yes there would be, i couldn't take time to give you a better answer. But i do something similar for the first relationship. What i do is add a check to see if the relationship was loaded and if it isn't then load the relationship before getting the count. This prevents it from loading for each result.

Comment: I updated my question with the produced query. If you have got the time, please take a look :)